# string replacement not replacing all instances

Tags: c#

Using C# in Visual Studio 13 - I'm trying to replace some slashes in my string using the replace command.  The VS tool tip tells me, "Returns a new string in which all occurrences of a specified Unicode character in this instance are replaced with another specified Unicode character"

My string, which is passed in as a parameter is:

```
path = "\\\\ServerName\\Folder1\\Folder2"
```

I create a new string:

```
string newPath = path.Replace(@"\\", @"//");
```

According to the tool tip it should replace all instances of \\ with //, but instead my resulting string is:

```
"//\\ServerName\\Folder1\\Folder2"
```

What am I doing wrong?  It seemed pretty straight forward to me, or so I thought.

What I'm trying to get is:

"////ServerName//Folder1//Folder2"

Comment: You should either use `@"\"` or `"\\"`.  In general it's best not to mix verbatim and non-verbatim strings the way you are.

Comment: That was my mistake.  I kept using the literal.

Answer (score 6):

Your output will be `//ServerName\Folder2\Folder2`, as there is only one actual occurrence of two backslashes, namely at the beginning of `\\ServerName`.

When inspecting a string's value, the debugger shows a single backslash (`\`) as two (`\\`), but when replacing, you want to replace one:

```
string newPath = path.Replace(@"\", @"/");
```

Note that you don't need to escape a slash character (`/`).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string newPath = path.Replace("\\", "/");
```

Your `path` string really is: `@"\\ServerName\Folder1\Folder2"`.